# MySql query - Como selecionar produtos que foram retornados antes de serem comprados usando sql apenas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela de um banco de dados mysql de movimento de produtos que contém os seguintes campos:

```
id | prod_id | prod_name | movimento_tipo | data_transaction
1  | idProd1 | tv        | ordemCompra    | 1-jan-2018
2  | idProd1 | tv        | shipped        | 3-jan-2018
3  | idProd2 | pc        | shipped        | 4-jan-2018
4  | idProd2 | pc        | ordemCompra    | 5-jan-2018
5  | idProd3 | sapato    | return         | 8-jan-2018
6  | idProd3 | sapato    | ordemCompra    | 7-jan-2018
7  | idProd4 | camisa    | ordemCompra    | 10-jan-2018
8  | idProd4 | camisa    | ordemCompra    | 12-jan-2018
```

O produto tv (idProd1) está correto. Teve uma ordem de compra em 1 jan e o shipping aconteceu em 3 de jan. O produto pc (idProd2) tem um erro, pois o shipping veio antes (4-jan) do que a compra (5-jan). Do mesmo jeito o sapato teve um retorno antes da compra. A camisa (idProd4 ) teve 2 ordens de compra mas não teve um retorno entre essas duas compras.

A minha pergunta é qual seria a query sql para capturar cada um desses erros. Eu não posso usar nenhuma lingua no backend (php ou python por exemplo) para filtrar essas situações.

Comment: qual a tabela que guarda a informação que o produto foi entregue ?

Comment: náo precisa. para esse cenário, o importante é só o shipping (quando foi enviado). Mas poderíamos aumentar a granularidade dos eventos. Afinal não poderia ser aceito um retorno sem o produto ter sido recebido. Mas como nem todos as entregas possuem assinatura e data de recebimento, esse campo ficaria null para alguns casos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução passa por ligar a tabela a si própria, através do código do produto, e usar a data_transaction para encontrar as instâncias de erro, i.e., situações que não deveriam poder ocorrer na realidade.

Como é o caso de, por exemplo:

- Devolver um produto que nunca foi comprado;
- Expedir um produto antes da order de compra dar entrada no sistema;
- Devolver duas vezes o produto sem que este tenha sido re-expedido entretanto.

Fica aqui apenas um exemplo, de como identificar os produtos para os quais a expedição (shipping) tem data anterior à compra. Usando este exemplo, penso que consiga criar a lógica para identificar as restantes situações de erro.

```
SELECT 'Expedicao antes da compra' AS SituacaoErro,
       t1.prod_id,
       t1.prod_nome,
       t1.movimento_tipo,
       t1.data_transaction AS DataDeExpedicao,
       t2.data_transaction AS DataDeCompra
  FROM tbl_tabela t1 -- Expedicao
 INNER JOIN tbl_tabela t2 -- Compra
    ON t2.prod_id = t1.prod_id
 WHERE t1.movimento_tipo = 'shipped'  
   AND t2.movimento_tipo = 'ordemCompra'
   AND t2.data_transaction > t1.data_transaction  -- A data da ordem de compra é posterior à data de compra.
```

Existem várias alternativas para obter o mesmo resultado (pode user o EXISTS, GROUP BY junto com HAVING, etc). Este é apenas um exemplo.

--Atualização após novo comentário

Extrapolando a situação para 3 movimentos, poderia adicionar mais um INNER JOIN ou talvez fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT prod_id,
            MAX(CASE WHEN movimento_tipo = 'ordemCompra' THEN data_transaction END)) AS DataOrdemCompra, -- Assumindo que pode ser vendido apenas uma vez
            MIN(CASE WHEN movimento_tipo = 'shipped' THEN data_transaction END)) AS DataExpedicao,  -- Data da primeira expedicao
            CASE WHEN movimento_tipo = 'return' THEN data_transaction END) AS DataDevolucao -- Data da devolucao
       FROM tbl_tabela
      GROUP BY prod_id
  ) Sumario
 WHERE Sumario.DataOrdemCompra > Sumario.DataExpedicao
    OR Sumario.DataDevolucao > Sumario.DataOrdemCompra
    OR Sumario.DataDevolucao > Sumario.DataExpedicao
```

Comment: entendi a lógica. Funciona quando estou comparando 2 movimentos que foi a minha pergunta. Mas extrapolando para um cenário onde eu preciso testar 3 ou mais movimentos como ficaria?. Ao que parece eu teria que criar um innerjoin com t1, t2, tn, para cada movimento. Ex. Retorne todos os movimentos que não obedecem a seguinte sequencia: dataOrdemDeCompra < dataShipped < dataReturn

Comment: Sim, para três movimentos, poderia fazer dessa forma. O único problema, pode ser nas situações em que um produto passa vários vezes pelos diferentes estados.

Comment: e esse é um cenário comum pois um produto pode ser potencialmente devolvido, comprado e enviado várias vezes.

Comment: Você pode criar uma FUNCTION !?